# How do I prevent memory leaks in Flex when rerunning effects?

Tags: apache-flex

This application is a much simplified version of what I am trying to accomplish, some smoothing of some motion on the screen by using a composite animation and rerunning it as things change, and using bindings to set some of the values of the animation. The animation is periodically stopped, and then restarted. valueFrom  is not set so a property value just continues from where it was towards a new goal. In this example, I'm animating a Rect's left/top towards mouse's X/Y to make it chase the mouse.

Problem is the memory of this application continues to grow if you wait a little while and continue to move the mouse. So what should I be doing that I am not?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication 
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
    creationComplete="creationCompleteHandler(event)"
    mouseMove="mouseMoveHandler(event)"
    mouseOut="mouseOutHandler(event)"
    >
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            private static const RECT_HALF_SIZE:int = 5;
            private static const NO_CHASE:int = -1000;

            [Bindable]
            private var lastMouseX:int = NO_CHASE;

            [Bindable]
            private var lastMouseY:int = NO_CHASE;

            private var evalTimer:Timer = new Timer(100);

            protected function creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                evalTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, function(event:TimerEvent):void { evalChase(); });
                evalTimer.start();
            }

            protected function mouseOutHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                lastMouseX = lastMouseY = NO_CHASE;
                evalChase();
            }

            protected function mouseMoveHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                const reStart:Boolean = (lastMouseX == NO_CHASE);

                lastMouseX = event.localX;
                lastMouseY = event.localY;

                if(reStart)
                    evalChase();
            }

            private function evalChase():void
            {
                doChase.stop();
                doChase.end();

                if(lastMouseX == NO_CHASE)
                    return;

                doChase.play();
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:Linear id="linearEaser" />
        <s:Parallel
            id="doChase"
            duration="2000"
            >
            <s:Animate target="{chaser}" easer="{linearEaser}" >
                <s:SimpleMotionPath property="left" valueTo="{lastMouseX-RECT_HALF_SIZE}" />
            </s:Animate>
            <s:Animate  target="{chaser}" easer="{linearEaser}" >
                <s:SimpleMotionPath property="top" valueTo="{lastMouseY-RECT_HALF_SIZE}" />
            </s:Animate>
        </s:Parallel>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:Rect
        id="chaser"
        top="0" left="0"
        width="{2*RECT_HALF_SIZE}" height="{2*RECT_HALF_SIZE}"
        >
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor color="red" />
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>

</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think you're actually doing anything wrong in this code, I copied into a new Flex 4.6 project and ran it, I could see what you're saying with regard to the ADL process itself increasing slightly in memory consumption over time, particularly after it stops motion then begins again, however I tried running this in Flash Builder with the profiler and it seems the swf itself isn't really leaking any memory, it stayed right around 1.1 MB for me (up to about 1.4, but then back down) it seems it had a fair amount of Vector.<*> objects in memory though I'm not clear on what is being stored in those objects.

Comment: Setting as the accepted answer because my much longer running of this simple app seems to confirm that memory is probably not leaking away in a release build as determined by my crude tool (Task Mananger), even though running ADL shows differently. I will have to go back to the original application and look past all those Vector.<*> objects to see if there are other types of memory leaking away, after I upgrade my FB Standard to Premium.